# How to load a stylesheet while using QQmlApplicationEngine

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qstylesheet

I am currently trying to load a stylesheet for a simple Qt5 application. Therefore I use the following code:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QFile styleFile("./css/style.qss");
styleFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString stylesheet = QLatin1String(styleFile.readAll());
app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load("./qml/main.qml");

app.exec();
```

However, the stylesheet is loaded correctly, but not applied. How do I have to change the above code, to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QML itself doesn't support stylesheets as `QWidget` does. But you still can customize your app in several ways. See [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qml_Styling) for more details.

As a workaround you can use some Third-party plugins, for example [Ableton.stylesheets](https://github.com/AbletonAG/aqt-stylesheets)